# Find TextView which was created programmatically?

Tags: java, android

How can I find those TextView's another function on same class?
I will use `setText()`, `serBackgroundColor()` after create.

This code part is on `CreateDesign()` and this func `calling onCreate()`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private LinearLayout linearLayout;
private TextView textView;

public void CreateDesign(){

   linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findById(R.id.linearLayout);

   for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
        textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setId(i);
        textView.setText(i + ". TextView");
        
        linearLayout.addView(textView);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well you're setting the ID of each from 1-5, so, try `findViewById(1)`?

Comment: `setId(i)` don't do this. Those IDs might already been taken. You can store them in variables

Comment: @TheWanderer yes it's work, thank u :)

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko how can I? I 'm new on Android, can u share your idea?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko guaranteed, IDs 0x1 to 0x5 aren't used. The resource ID format prevents IDs from being smaller than 0x10000000.

Comment: yeah I see, I will do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you don't necessarily need to use id here, There are several ways to achieve this:

1.

```
TextView textView = (TextView) linearLayout.findViewById(i);
```

`i` is what you set before from 1 to 5.

2.

```
TextView textView = (TextView) linearLayout.getChildAt(i);
```

`i` here is the number of set item, for instance `i=0` is the first textView you added using addView() method.

Answer (score 2):

Either you create a member variable of this TextView which you can then use inside this class or you can use findViewById() on your LinearLayout.

Comment: You're welcome. If you need anything more just leave a comment and I will hopefully be able to help you out!

Answer (score 2):

Use the normal `findViewById()` method. You're giving the TextViews unique IDs from 1 to 5, so you can find those TextViews by supplying 1-5 to `findViewById()`.

However, you probably shouldn't be doing it this way, and you shouldn't have a global `textView` variable (it'll only hold a reference to the last-created TextView).

Instead, try using an ArrayList and adding all of your TextViews to it. Then you won't need to give them IDs that don't follow the standards.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private LinearLayout linearLayout;
    private ArrayList<TextView> textViews = new ArrayList<>();

    public void CreateDesign(){

        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findById(R.id.linearLayout);

        for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setText(i + ". TextView");

            linearLayout.addView(textView);
            textViews.add(textView); //add it to the ArrayList
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow I'm impressed, that's look like more systematic. I will try it now.